# Dll referencing in CSharpCodeProvider only works when it's set to .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-3.5, csharpcodeprovider

When I set my CSharpCodeProvider class to use .NET 3.5 it errors trying to load certain referenced DLLs:

```
Line number 0, Error Number: CS0006, 'Metadata file 'System.Linq.dll' could not be found;
Line number 0, Error Number: CS0006, 'Metadata file 'System.Collections.dll' could not be found;
```

The thing is, if I set it to 2.0 it works, but it can't use LINQ.

Now in other threads there are solutions saying that it's because the DLL isn't in the right place, and offer solutions such as:

```
typeof(System.Xml.Linq.Extensions).Assembly.Location
```

To get the location of the Linq location, but due to the way my program works I don't know what DLLs I may need to load. This isn't a problem for external libraries, as the user needs to input where they are anyway, but for System dlls am I able to get their location with just `"System.Linq"` or `"System.Collections"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of `System.Collections.dll` or `System.Linq.dll`. Most of LINQ is in `System.Core.dll`, and the collections are in `mscorlib` and `System.dll` IIRC. You need to differentiate between *namespaces* and *assemblies*. (You use `using` directives to import namespaces, and add references to assemblies within the project.)

Which classes are you interested in? Look them up in MSDN to see which assemblies they're in.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Is there anyway to lookup assemblies for namespaces that are in standard .NET assemblies using a built in method or reflection? For example go from `System.Linq` to `System.Core.dll`

Comment: @Blam: No, because there isn't a 1:1 mapping. An assembly can contribute to many namespaces, and a namespace can contain types from many assemblies. They're orthogonal concepts which just *happen* to often have a relationship.